# Filter options not working for ngx-datatables in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8

Tried for filter option in ngx-datatables for all columns but not working. I have written code but it i9s not working. Where I did a mistake in my code. Anyone can help me to find the solutions.

app.component.html:

```
    <label> Name </label>
    <input
      #name
      id="search"
      type="text"
      class="form-control"
      placeholder="Search"
      aria-label="Search"
      aria-describedby="basic-addon1"
    />

    <label> Company </label>
    <input
      #company
      id="search"
      type="text"
      class="form-control"
      placeholder="Search"
      aria-label="Search"
      aria-describedby="basic-addon1"
    />

    <label> Date  </label>
    <input
      #date
      id="search"
      type="text"
      class="form-control"
      placeholder="Search"
      aria-label="Search"
      aria-describedby="basic-addon1"
    />


    <button (click)="updateTable()"> Search </button> 

  <ngx-datatable #table class="bootstrap ngx-datatable" [columns]="columns" [rows]="rows" [columnMode]="'force'"
    [headerHeight]="35" [rowHeight]="'auto'" [footerHeight]="50" [limit]="10">
  </ngx-datatable>
```

app.component.ts:

```
  updateTable() { 
      let filterName = this.name.nativeElement.value
      .toString()
      .toLowerCase()
      .trim();
      let filterCompany = this.company.nativeElement.value
      .toString()
      .toLowerCase()
      .trim();
      let filterDate = this.date.nativeElement.value
      .toString()
      .toLowerCase()
      .trim();

  this.rows = this.filteredData.filter(item => {
     for (let i = 0; i < this.columnsWithSearch.length; i++) {
    var colValue = item[this.columnsWithSearch[i]];

    if (
      !filterName ||
      !filterCompany ||
      !filterDate ||
      (!!colValue &&
        colValue
          .toString()
          .toLowerCase()
          .indexOf(filterName) !== -1)
    ) {
      return true;
    }
  }
});
}
```

Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngx-datatables-filter-all-columns-evltmj?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your main issue is with your condition:

```js
if (
  !filterName ||
  !filterCompany ||
  !filterDate ||
  (!!colValue &&
    colValue
      .toString()
      .toLowerCase()
      .indexOf(filterName) !== -1)
)
```

If one of your 3 fields (filterName, filterCompany or filterDate) is empty, then your filter will return true. Also you only search for a match with `filterName`

You could replace your 3 variables with an object `filter = {name: '', company: '', date: ''}` and then change your condition to:

```js
const filterValue = filter[this.columnsWithSearch[i]];
if (
  !filterValue ||
  (!!colValue &&
    colValue
      .toString()
      .toLowerCase()
      .indexOf(filterValue) !== -1)
) {
  return true;
}
```

Also for a cleaner code, I would advise you to look into [Angular pipe](https://angular.io/guide/pipes) which would allow you to have a more optimized system and add a "real time" search.

Comment: @Sansara I made a fork here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngx-datatables-filter-all-columns-gxhfkg?file=src/app/app.component.ts